# a:active not working on phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, cordova

What I want to do is when I click on any li element it should change color.The problem is that when I put a:active it works on android 4.0 and higher but it does not work on android 2.3 and lower.I dont know what the problem is.Is there any alternative way by which I can change the background color of li when I press it?

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="#">Requirements</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Release dates</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Game Plot</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Game Review</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
<li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
#navigation a:active
{color:pink;
background-color:#FF5C33;
}
```

Note:
a:hover works on android 2.3 and below.

Comment: you forgot `#` for id `#navigation`

Comment: srry I forgot to copy that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use javascript to do this for you, rather than rely on pseudo selectors.

Change your css to this...

```
#navigation a.active {
    color:pink;
    background-color:#FF5C33;
}
```

and add this javascript...

```
$(function() {
    $("#navigation a").on("mousedown", function() {
        $(this).addClass("active");
    }).on("mouseup", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active");
    });
});
```

That should work in earlier versions of Android, which will use an older version of WebView.

Comment: looks ok but pseudo class `:active` isn't equivalent of click, but on mousedown and need to be removed on mouseup

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes - thanks for spotting that.  I'd misread the question and despite using `:active` I thought he meant when clicked.

Answer (score 1):

Using inspiration from @Archer's answer, you could use javascript for that:

```
$(function() {
    $("#navigation a").on("mousedown mouseup", function() {
         $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J66hX/)

Comment: Much cleaner than my "fixed" answer (thanks), but I'll not delete mine as it has the css change in it as well.

Comment: Now wondering, are 'mousedown mouseup' correctly supported on targeted device?... Could use instead touchstart and touchend event, maybe? And still, could get some downside i'm not aware of

Comment: I'm currently working on a Cordova app myself, and the minefield that is mouse/touch events.  We could be here all week if we got into it!  I think for the purpose of this question mousedown & mouseup are correct (until tomorrow!)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question but I am still having the same problem.It is working in browser and also working in android 4.0 and higher but still not working on android 2.3.